# QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Window "", which already has a layout

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

As the title states, I'm having an issue trying to set a form layout to a window - I'm not sure what exactly it means by "already has a layout" as I have no explicitly called setLayout, so is there some default layout that gets applied to a window? Or does it have something to do with my super call?

Searching didn't get me a proper answer (at least not for my case), so I figured I'd make a post.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

#Window class
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): # constructor for Window (passes "self" -aka Window- to __init__ to initialize it)
        super(Window, self).__init__() #inherits from QMainWindow
        self.setGeometry(50,50,800,600) #Set window dimensions
        self.setWindowTitle("Google Music Playlist Transfer") #Set window title
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('gmusic.png')) #Set window icon
        self.home()

    def home(self):     
        #Set email field
        email = QLineEdit()
        email.setMaxLength(110)
        email.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

        #Set password field
        pwd = QLineEdit()
        pwd.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        pwd.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        #Form layout
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow("Email: ", email)
        layout.addRow("Password: ", pwd)

        #Login button
        login_btn = QPushButton("Login", self) #login button
        login_btn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit) #tell button what to do
        login_btn.resize(100, 100)
        login_btn.move(100,100)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show() #Show window
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue for any future passersby (Though I don't know exactly why it is an issue, maybe someone can expand on it in a comment) - I was inheriting from QWindow instead of QWidget, apparently this causes some sort of issue with setting the layout - again, not sure why, but changing that to QWidget did fix the problem!

Comment: Thank god. That would have taken me aeons